# how to set change the date picker's UI

Tags: java, android, user-interface, datepicker

hi the following image is the UI of the date picker i am currently using
[image]

But i want the date picker to be as follows
[image]

the second one is the image of an iPhone App. how can i get like this. Is there any possibilities. pls help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/)..Click Download and Download the Wheel zip..